# Minimum Sample Size for a Two Stage IPD Meta-Analysis

Tags: r, meta-analysis, network-meta-analysis

I am attempting to run a IPD meta-analysis and I have 12 total studies with sample sizes ranging from 3 to 40 and was wondering is there is a minimum number to conduct a two-stage IPD, specifically as it relates to the first stage as I would need to conduct a Cox model.

Additionally, the studies contain varying amounts patients for 3 different groups (i.e some studies only contain patients from 1,2 or all 3 groups) and I wanted to conduct an IPD that included analysis of A vs C, B vs C, A vs B, and (A+B) vs C.

Given the small sample size per study, it seems that a two-stage analysis is unlikely and I will have to conduct a one-stage analysis and was wondering if I would be able to compare those groups (A vs C, B vs C, A vs B, and (A+B) vs C).

Note, I am using R and was wondering the best package for either one or two-stage IPD.

Thanks!

Comment: One stage seems preferable as your chances of running the Cox model with a sample size of 3 are somewhere between slim and negligible.

Comment: I would consider using a multivariate meta-analysis approach for the 2-stage analysis